# Python Tkinter Button Issues (Twitch bot)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a test Tkinter button for my twitch chat bot. What this button would do when clicked is send a simple message to the channel it's connected to. However, I am encountering some issues when trying to figure out how to do this. I have the basic button created, however I get this console error when clicking it:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Cosmicluck\Desktop\bot.py", line 122, in commandTest
    send_message(CHAN, "Click!")
  File "C:\Users\Cosmicluck\Desktop\bot.py", line 30, in send_message
    con.send(bytes('PRIVMSG %s :%s\r\n' % (chan, msg), 'UTF-8'))
NameError: name 'con' is not defined
```

Now it's saying "con" is not defined, however I don't need to define it because the commands I have set up work perfectly fine. Here is the code the NameError is referencing:

```
def send_pong(msg):
    con.send(bytes('PONG %s\r\n' % msg, 'UTF-8'))

def send_message(chan, msg):
    con.send(bytes('PRIVMSG %s :%s\r\n' % (chan, msg), 'UTF-8'))

def send_nick(nick):
    con.send(bytes('NICK %s\r\n' % nick, 'UTF-8'))

def send_pass(password):
    con.send(bytes('PASS %s\r\n' % password, 'UTF-8'))

def join_channel(chan):
    con.send(bytes('JOIN %s\r\n' % chan, 'UTF-8'))

def part_channel(chan):
    con.send(bytes('PART %s\r\n' % chan, 'UTF-8'))
```

And finally here is my Tkinter button code:

```
master = Tk()

def commandTest():
    send_message(CHAN, "Click!")

b = Button(master, text="OK", command=commandTest)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

I'm hoping someone can explain how this could be fixed, and if it's even possible to do. Thanks!

Comment: If Python says it isn't defined, it isn't defined. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "however I don't need to define it because the commands I have set up work perfectly fine". I don't understand. You said you're getting an error, so it must not be working perfectly fine.

Comment: where is 'con' in your code...someone's seeing it?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Here is the code ( I stripped away the information that was un-needed or should not be shown to anyone, and I know the socket will die repeatedly, thats because I removed the bots authorization code for safety) http://pastebin.com/QDJDnE5m

Comment: Include it in the post. If you feel that it's too big to include, it's probably not Minimal.

Comment: `mainloop` loops forever for as long as the window remains open, so none of the variables created after that will exist until the user closes the window. `con` happens to be one of those variables. So you can't reference it in any of the button commands.

Comment: The code in the pastebin is everything required for the bot itself to work, with the Tkinter button code

Comment: I realize that the external link contains the needed code. What I'm strongly suggesting is that you actually include that code in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it appears you are attempting to call `mainloop()` before connecting to the socket. If the name implies that it is, in fact, the 'main loop', you need to call the `mainloop()` AFTER calling;

```
con = socket.socket()
con.connect((HOST, PORT))

send_pass(PASS)
send_nick(NICK)
join_channel(CHAN)
```

--Hence, changing

```
mainloop()

con = socket.socket()
con.connect((HOST, PORT))

send_pass(PASS)
send_nick(NICK)
join_channel(CHAN)

data = ""
```

to;

```
con = socket.socket()
con.connect((HOST, PORT))

send_pass(PASS)
send_nick(NICK)
join_channel(CHAN)

data = ""

mainloop()
```

You will more than likely have to do a bit of other debugging, but, this *should* fix your 'con is not defined' issue.

Comment: This did work, it sends the message to the channel now perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `con` referenced in your commands function is local and is not the same `con` defined in line 110:

`con = socket.socket()`

add parameter to your commands function, this way:

```
def send_pong(msg, conn):
    conn.send(bytes('PONG %s\r\n' % msg, 'UTF-8'))
```

And when calling these functions, pass it as parameters:

`send_pong(line[1],con)`